# NIC Intel 520 to send mbuf packet with multi segments

Tags: dpdk

I reassemble two small packets to one big packet,
and then do ip fragment this big packet to two packets.
and then call send_burst(rte_eth_tx_burst) to transfer packet to NIC.

nb_seg==1 packet can send, but nb_seg>1 cannot pass Tx.(GBIC:Brocade 57-0000075-01)

Does NIC intel 520 support multi-segs?

Here is my NIC information

```
82:00.1 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet 10G 2P X520 Adapter (rev 01)
        Subsystem: Intel Corporation 10GbE 2P X520 Adapter
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 199, NUMA node 1
        Memory at c8000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
        I/O ports at 8000 [size=32]
        Memory at c8200000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
        Expansion ROM at <ignored> [disabled]
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel driver in use: ixgbe
        Kernel modules: ixgbe
```

I have tried to set ixgbe_set_tx_function
**dev->tx_pkt_burst = ixgbe_xmit_pkts;**
and only run **else** code.

```
void __attribute__((cold))
ixgbe_set_tx_function(struct rte_eth_dev *dev, struct ixgbe_tx_queue *txq)
{
        /* Use a simple Tx queue (no offloads, no multi segs) if possible */

        if ((txq->offloads == 0) &&
#ifdef RTE_LIBRTE_SECURITY
                        !(txq->using_ipsec) &&
#endif
                        (txq->tx_rs_thresh >= RTE_PMD_IXGBE_TX_MAX_BURST)) {
                PMD_INIT_LOG(DEBUG, "Using simple tx code path");
                dev->tx_pkt_prepare = NULL;
#ifdef RTE_IXGBE_INC_VECTOR
                if (txq->tx_rs_thresh <= RTE_IXGBE_TX_MAX_FREE_BUF_SZ &&
                                (rte_eal_process_type() != RTE_PROC_PRIMARY ||
                                        ixgbe_txq_vec_setup(txq) == 0)) {
                        PMD_INIT_LOG(DEBUG, "Vector tx enabled.");
                        dev->tx_pkt_burst = ixgbe_xmit_pkts_vec;
                } else
#endif
                dev->tx_pkt_burst = ixgbe_xmit_pkts_simple;
        } else {

                PMD_INIT_LOG(DEBUG, "Using full-featured tx code path");
                PMD_INIT_LOG(DEBUG,
                                " - offloads = 0x%" PRIx64,
                                txq->offloads);
                PMD_INIT_LOG(DEBUG,
                                " - tx_rs_thresh = %lu " "[RTE_PMD_IXGBE_TX_MAX_BURST=%lu]",
                                (unsigned long)txq->tx_rs_thresh,
                                (unsigned long)RTE_PMD_IXGBE_TX_MAX_BURST);
                dev->tx_pkt_burst = ixgbe_xmit_pkts;
                dev->tx_pkt_prepare = ixgbe_prep_pkts;
        }
}
```

I have set offload to DEV_TX_OFFLOAD_MULTI_SEGS

```
 193     .txmode = {
 194         .mq_mode = ETH_MQ_TX_NONE,
 195         .offloads = (DEV_TX_OFFLOAD_IPV4_CKSUM |DEV_TX_OFFLOAD_MULTI_SEGS),
```

I use DPDK 19.11.11 (LTS)

sudo ethtool -i enp5s0f0

```
driver: ixgbe
version: 5.1.0-k
firmware-version: 0x800007f5
expansion-rom-version:
bus-info: 0000:05:00.0
supports-statistics: yes
supports-test: yes
supports-eeprom-access: yes
supports-register-dump: yes
supports-priv-flags: yes
```

sudo lshw -c Network | grep X520 -B10

```
       version: 01
       serial: a0:36:9f:e4:2d:10
       capacity: 10Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi msix pciexpress vpd bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical fibre 1000bt-fd 10000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=ixgbe driverversion=5.1.0-k firmware=0x800008c1 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=fibre
       resources: irq:169 memory:c8100000-c81fffff ioport:8020(size=32) memory:c8204000-c8207fff memory:c8280000-c82fffff memory:3c000000000-3c0000fffff memory:3c000100000-3c0001fffff
  *-network:1 DISABLED
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Ethernet 10G 2P X520 Adapter
```

here is my fragment program, I do pkt_mbuf dump on line 246

```
129 static int do_pkt_fragment(struct rte_mbuf *m, uint16_t port_out, struct lcore_conf *qconf)
130 {
131     struct lcore_rx_queue *rxq = NULL;
132     const struct rte_ether_hdr *eth;
133     uint16_t ether_type;
134     struct rte_ether_addr ether_src, ether_dst;
135
136     uint32_t i, len;
137     int32_t len2=0, queueid = 0;
138     uint64_t ol_flags = 0;
139
140     rxq = &qconf->rx_queue_list[queueid];
141
142     /* save ether type of the incoming packet */
143     eth = rte_pktmbuf_mtod(m, const struct rte_ether_hdr *);
144
145     /* copy ether information */
146     ether_type = eth->ether_type;
147     rte_ether_addr_copy(&eth->s_addr, &ether_src);
148     rte_ether_addr_copy(&eth->d_addr, &ether_dst);
149
150     char buf[RTE_ETHER_ADDR_FMT_SIZE];
151     printf("[mac] %d\n",RTE_ETHER_ADDR_FMT_SIZE);
152     rte_ether_format_addr(buf, RTE_ETHER_ADDR_FMT_SIZE,&(ether_dst));
153     printf("%s\n",buf);
154     rte_ether_format_addr(buf, RTE_ETHER_ADDR_FMT_SIZE,&(ether_src));
155     printf("%s\n",buf);
156
157     /* Remove the Ethernet header and trailer from the input packet */
158     rte_pktmbuf_adj(m, (uint16_t)sizeof(struct rte_ether_hdr));
159
160     /* Build transmission burst */
161     len = qconf->tx_mbufs[port_out].len;
162
163     /* if this is an IPv4 packet */
164     if (RTE_ETH_IS_IPV4_HDR(m->packet_type)) {
165
166         /* if we don't need to do any fragmentation */
167         if (likely (IPV4_MTU_DEFAULT >= m->pkt_len)) {
168             qconf->tx_mbufs[port_out].m_table[len] = m;
169             len2 = 1;
170         } else {
171             //printf("[before frag]frag port %d, m->pkt_len%d\n", port_out, m->pkt_len);
172             ////rte_pktmbuf_dump(stdout, m, 32);
173
174             //printf("[frag]ethsrc:%x%x,ethdst:%x%x\n",
175                //     ether_src.addr_bytes[0], ether_src.addr_bytes[1],
176                 //    ether_dst.addr_bytes[0], ether_dst.addr_bytes[1] );
177             len2 = rte_ipv4_fragment_packet(m,
178                     &qconf->tx_mbufs[port_out].m_table[len],
179                     (uint16_t)(MBUF_TABLE_SIZE - len),
180                     IPV4_MTU_DEFAULT,
181                     rxq->direct_pool, rxq->indirect_pool);
182
183             /*printf("dipool:%d  inuse:%d full:%d\n",rte_mempool_avail_count(socket_direct_pool),
184                                                    rte_mempool_in_use_count(socket_direct_pool),
185                                                    rte_mempool_full(socket_direct_pool));
186             printf("inpool:%d  inuse:%d full:%d\n",rte_mempool_avail_count(socket_indirect_pool),
187                                                    rte_mempool_in_use_count(socket_indirect_pool),
188                                                    rte_mempool_full(socket_indirect_pool));
189
190             printf(" [frag finish]len2 %d, len %d\n",len2, len);
191
192             for (i = len; i < len + len2; i ++) {
193                 rte_pktmbuf_free(qconf->tx_mbufs[port_out].m_table[i]);
194             }*/
195             //rte_pktmbuf_dump(stdout, qconf->tx_mbufs[port_out].m_table[len], 32);
196             //rte_pktmbuf_dump(stdout, qconf->tx_mbufs[port_out].m_table[len]->next, 32);
197             //rte_pktmbuf_dump(stdout, qconf->tx_mbufs[port_out].m_table[len+1], 32);
198             //rte_pktmbuf_dump(stdout, qconf->tx_mbufs[port_out].m_table[len+1]->next, 32);
199             /* Free input packet */
200             rte_pktmbuf_free(m);
201
202             /* request HW to regenerate IPv4 cksum */
203             ol_flags |= (PKT_TX_IPV4 | PKT_TX_IP_CKSUM);
204
205             /* If we fail to fragment the packet */
206             if (unlikely (len2 < 0))
207                 return -1;
208         }
209     } else {
210         /* else, just forward the packet */
211         qconf->tx_mbufs[port_out].m_table[len] = m;
212         len2 = 1;
213     }
214
215     for (i = len; i < len + len2; i ++) {
216
217         m = qconf->tx_mbufs[port_out].m_table[i];
218         //printf("m %lx\n",(long)m);
219
220         /* prepend an ether_header  */
221         struct rte_ether_hdr *eth_hdr = NULL;
222         eth_hdr = (struct rte_ether_hdr *)
223                   rte_pktmbuf_prepend(m, (uint16_t)sizeof(struct rte_ether_hdr));
224
225         if (eth_hdr == NULL) {
226             rte_panic("No headroom in mbuf.\n");
227         }
228
229         m->ol_flags |= ol_flags;
230         m->l2_len = sizeof(struct rte_ether_hdr);
231
232         /* dst addr */
233         rte_ether_addr_copy(&ether_dst, &eth_hdr->d_addr);
234         /* src addr */
235         rte_ether_addr_copy(&ether_src, &eth_hdr->s_addr);
236         /* ether type */
237         eth_hdr->ether_type = ether_type;
238
239         //printf("port %d\n",m->port);
240         m->port = port_out;
241
242         struct rte_ipv4_hdr *ipv4_hdr = NULL;
243         ipv4_hdr = rte_pktmbuf_mtod_offset(m, struct rte_ipv4_hdr *,sizeof(struct rte_ether_hdr));
244
245         printf("id %x,total_len %d\n",ntohs(ipv4_hdr->packet_id),ntohs(ipv4_hdr->total_length));
246         rte_pktmbuf_dump(stdout, m, m->pkt_len);
247
248         //printf("[frag_af]ethsrc%x%x,ethdst%x%x\n",
249           //      eth_hdr->s_addr.addr_bytes[0], eth_hdr->s_addr.addr_bytes[1],
250             //    eth_hdr->d_addr.addr_bytes[0], eth_hdr->d_addr.addr_bytes[1] );
251         //printf("frag len %d, port %d\n",m->pkt_len,m->port);
252         //rte_pktmbuf_dump(stdout, m, 40);
253     }
254
255     return len2;
256 }
```

Here is send_burst part

```
128 send_burst(struct lcore_conf *qconf, uint16_t n, uint16_t port)
129 {
130     struct rte_mbuf **m_table;
131     int ret;
132     uint16_t queueid;
133
134     queueid = qconf->tx_queue_id[port];
135     m_table = (struct rte_mbuf **)qconf->tx_mbufs[port].m_table;
136     for(int i=0;i<n; i++) {
137         struct rte_ipv4_hdr *ipv4_hdr = NULL;
138         ipv4_hdr = rte_pktmbuf_mtod_offset(m_table[i], struct rte_ipv4_hdr *,sizeof(struct rte_ether_hdr));
139
140         printf("[burst]id %x,total_len %d\n",ntohs(ipv4_hdr->packet_id),ntohs(ipv4_hdr->total_length));
141         //rte_pktmbuf_dump(stdout, m_table[i], m_table[i]->pkt_len);
142     }
143     ret = rte_eth_tx_burst(port, queueid, m_table, n);
144
145     printf("ret %d, len %d\n",ret, n);
146     //os_log_debug("send_burst port id:%d, queueid:%d original:%d ret:%d\n",port,queueid,n,ret);
147     //os_log_debug("pktmbuf_pool:%d  inuse:%d full:%d\n",rte_mempool_avail_count(pktmbuf_pool),rte_mempool_in_use_count(pktmb    uf_pool),rte_mempool_full(pktmbuf_pool));
148     if (unlikely(ret < n)) {
149         do {
150             rte_pktmbuf_free(m_table[ret]);
151         } while (++ret < n);
152     }
153
154     return 0;
155 }
```

here is log

```
B4:A5:EF:FE:4F:7B
7C:E2:CA:28:46:4E
id f442,total_len 1500
dump mbuf at 0x138797f40, iova=2781397fc0, buf_len=2176
  pkt_len=1514, ol_flags=c0000000000000, nb_segs=3, in_port=1
  segment at 0x138797f40, data=0x138798032, data_len=34
  Dump data at [0x138798032], len=34
00000000: B4 A5 EF FE 4F 7B 7C E2 CA 28 46 4E 08 00 45 38 | ....O{|..(FN..E8
00000010: 05 DC F4 42 20 00 FD 11 00 00 0A 1E 01 14 0A 1E | ...B ...........
00000020: 22 02                                           | ".
  segment at 0x12209e5c0, data=0x101b09722, data_len=48
  Dump data at [0x101b09722], len=48
00000000: F7 D1 08 68 05 CE 00 00 30 FF 05 BE 01 00 13 08 | ...h....0.......
00000010: 45 00 05 BE 0C 1E 00 00 37 06 0F 9B AC D9 A3 28 | E.......7......(
00000020: 0A FF 07 81 01 BB EA 4C 1B A1 E4 20 E3 0C A2 33 | .......L... ...3
  segment at 0x12209e680, data=0x101b084a2, data_len=1432
  Dump data at [0x101b084a2], len=1432
00000000: 80 10 01 05 77 B2 00 00 01 01 08 0A 54 5D B1 EF | ....w.......T]..
00000010: 02 E2 D4 51 16 03 03 00 4C 02 00 00 48 03 03 62 | ...Q....L...H..b
00000020: 3D 59 B0 41 70 49 6A 08 25 8D 62 7A 61 16 91 E2 | =Y.ApIj.%.bza...
00000030: 47 77 5E EE B5 CE 4B 44 4F 57 4E 47 52 44 01 00 | Gw^...KDOWNGRD..
00000040: C0 2B 00 00 20 00 17 00 00 FF 01 00 01 00 00 0B | .+.. ...........
00000050: 00 02 01 00 00 23 00 00 00 10 00 05 00 03 02 68 | .....#.........h
00000060: 32 75 50 00 00 16 03 03 10 FB 0B 00 10 F7 00 10 | 2uP.............
00000070: F4 00 05 EB 30 82 05 E7 30 82 04 CF A0 03 02 01 | ....0...0.......
00000080: 02 02 11 00 AB B9 14 A7 31 D1 08 01 0A 00 00 00 | ........1.......
00000090: 01 3B 06 34 30 0D 06 09 2A 86 48 86 F7 0D 01 01 | .;.40...*.H.....
000000A0: 0B 05 00 30 46 31 0B 30 09 06 03 55 04 06 13 02 | ...0F1.0...U....
000000B0: 55 53 31 22 30 20 06 03 55 04 0A 13 19 47 6F 6F | US1"0 ..U....Goo
000000C0: 67 6C 65 20 54 72 75 73 74 20 53 65 72 76 69 63 | gle Trust Servic
000000D0: 65 73 20 4C 4C 43 31 13 30 11 06 03 55 04 03 13 | es LLC1.0...U...
000000E0: 0A 47 54 53 20 43 41 20 31 43 33 30 1E 17 0D 32 | .GTS CA 1C30...2
000000F0: 32 30 33 31 37 31 30 32 35 30 30 5A 17 0D 32 32 | 20317102500Z..22
00000100: 30 36 30 39 31 30 32 34 35 39 5A 30 21 31 1F 30 | 0609102459Z0!1.0
00000110: 1D 06 03 55 04 03 0C 16 2A 2E 67 6F 6F 67 6C 65 | ...U....*.google
00000120: 2D 61 6E 61 6C 79 74 69 63 73 2E 63 6F 6D 30 59 | -analytics.com0Y
00000130: 30 13 06 07 2A 86 48 CE 3D 02 01 06 08 2A 86 48 | 0...*.H.=....*.H
00000140: CE 3D 03 01 07 03 42 00 04 59 AF 76 87 46 01 40 | .=....B..Y.v.F.@
00000150: 27 C4 70 5A 70 AC 40 BF 9C F6 6B 28 89 81 28 AF | '.pZp.@...k(..(.
00000160: 66 31 DA 67 57 B2 8D 56 08 B7 80 2D AE B5 9E 9F | f1.gW..V...-....
00000170: 24 60 FD 2B 0C BF 30 4B 59 DC 2B F1 21 B6 16 0F | $`.+..0KY.+.!...
00000180: F1 50 4D FE 1B 95 70 E8 EB A3 82 03 BE 30 82 03 | .PM...p......0..
00000190: BA 30 0E 06 03 55 1D 0F 01 01 FF 04 04 03 02 07 | .0...U..........
000001A0: 80 30 13 06 03 55 1D 25 04 0C 30 0A 06 08 2B 06 | .0...U.%..0...+.
000001B0: 01 05 05 07 03 01 30 0C 06 03 55 1D 13 01 01 FF | ......0...U.....
000001C0: 04 02 30 00 30 1D 06 03 55 1D 0E 04 16 04 14 B4 | ..0.0...U.......
000001D0: C6 30 23 87 C5 84 6D 58 65 D3 6D 33 97 E5 71 EE | .0#...mXe.m3..q.
000001E0: F5 E4 1C 30 1F 06 03 55 1D 23 04 18 30 16 80 14 | ...0...U.#..0...
000001F0: 8A 74 7F AF 85 CD EE 95 CD 3D 9C D0 E2 46 14 F3 | .t.......=...F..
00000200: 71 35 1D 27 30 6A 06 08 2B 06 01 05 05 07 01 01 | q5.'0j..+.......
00000210: 04 5E 30 5C 30 27 06 08 2B 06 01 05 05 07 30 01 | .^0\0'..+.....0.
00000220: 86 1B 68 74 74 70 3A 2F 2F 6F 63 73 70 2E 70 6B | ..http://ocsp.pk
00000230: 69 2E 67 6F 6F 67 2F 67 74 73 31 63 33 30 31 06 | i.goog/gts1c301.
00000240: 08 2B 06 01 05 05 07 30 02 86 25 68 74 74 70 3A | .+.....0..%http:
00000250: 2F 2F 70 6B 69 2E 67 6F 6F 67 2F 72 65 70 6F 2F | //pki.goog/repo/
00000260: 63 65 72 74 73 2F 67 74 73 31 63 33 2E 64 65 72 | certs/gts1c3.der
00000270: 30 82 01 6F 06 03 55 1D 11 04 82 01 66 30 82 01 | 0..o..U.....f0..
00000280: 62 82 16 2A 2E 67 6F 6F 67 6C 65 2D 61 6E 61 6C | b..*.google-anal
00000290: 79 74 69 63 73 2E 63 6F 6D 82 1B 72 65 67 69 6F | ytics.com..regio
000002A0: 6E 31 2E 61 70 70 2D 6D 65 61 73 75 72 65 6D 65 | n1.app-measureme
000002B0: 6E 74 2E 63 6F 6D 82 13 61 70 70 2D 6D 65 61 73 | nt.com..app-meas
000002C0: 75 72 65 6D 65 6E 74 2E 63 6F 6D 82 14 67 6F 6F | urement.com..goo
000002D0: 67 6C 65 2D 61 6E 61 6C 79 74 69 63 73 2E 63 6F | gle-analytics.co
000002E0: 6D 82 1C 72 65 67 69 6F 6E 31 2E 67 6F 6F 67 6C | m..region1.googl
000002F0: 65 2D 61 6E 61 6C 79 74 69 63 73 2E 63 6F 6D 82 | e-analytics.com.
00000300: 18 73 73 6C 2E 67 6F 6F 67 6C 65 2D 61 6E 61 6C | .ssl.google-anal
00000310: 79 74 69 63 73 2E 63 6F 6D 82 18 77 77 77 2E 67 | ytics.com..www.g
00000320: 6F 6F 67 6C 65 2D 61 6E 61 6C 79 74 69 63 73 2E | oogle-analytics.
00000330: 63 6F 6D 82 1C 72 65 67 69 6F 6E 31 2E 61 6E 61 | com..region1.ana
00000340: 6C 79 74 69 63 73 2E 67 6F 6F 67 6C 65 2E 63 6F | lytics.google.co
00000350: 6D 82 14 67 6F 6F 67 6C 65 74 61 67 6D 61 6E 61 | m..googletagmana
00000360: 67 65 72 2E 63 6F 6D 82 18 77 77 77 2E 67 6F 6F | ger.com..www.goo
00000370: 67 6C 65 74 61 67 6D 61 6E 61 67 65 72 2E 63 6F | gletagmanager.co
00000380: 6D 82 0A 75 72 63 68 69 6E 2E 63 6F 6D 82 12 73 | m..urchin.com..s
00000390: 65 72 76 69 63 65 2E 75 72 63 68 69 6E 2E 63 6F | ervice.urchin.co
000003A0: 6D 82 08 66 70 73 2E 67 6F 6F 67 82 0A 2A 2E 66 | m..fps.goog..*.f
000003B0: 70 73 2E 67 6F 6F 67 82 12 67 6F 6F 67 6C 65 6F | ps.goog..googleo
000003C0: 70 74 69 6D 69 7A 65 2E 63 6F 6D 82 16 77 77 77 | ptimize.com..www
000003D0: 2E 67 6F 6F 67 6C 65 6F 70 74 69 6D 69 7A 65 2E | .googleoptimize.
000003E0: 63 6F 6D 30 21 06 03 55 1D 20 04 1A 30 18 30 08 | com0!..U. ..0.0.
000003F0: 06 06 67 81 0C 01 02 01 30 0C 06 0A 2B 06 01 04 | ..g.....0...+...
00000400: 01 D6 79 02 05 03 30 3C 06 03 55 1D 1F 04 35 30 | ..y...0<..U...50
00000410: 33 30 31 A0 2F A0 2D 86 2B 68 74 74 70 3A 2F 2F | 301./.-.+http://
00000420: 63 72 6C 73 2E 70 6B 69 2E 67 6F 6F 67 2F 67 74 | crls.pki.goog/gt
00000430: 73 31 63 33 2F 51 4F 76 4A 30 4E 31 73 54 32 41 | s1c3/QOvJ0N1sT2A
00000440: 2E 63 72 6C 30 82 01 03 06 0A 2B 06 01 04 01 D6 | .crl0.....+.....
00000450: 79 02 04 02 04 81 F4 04 81 F1 00 EF 00 75 00 51 | y............u.Q
00000460: A3 B0 F5 FD 01 79 9C 56 6D B8 37 78 8F 0C A4 7A | .....y.Vm.7x...z
00000470: CC 1B 27 CB F7 9E 88 42 9A 0D FE D4 8B 05 E5 00 | ..'....B........
00000480: 00 01 7F 97 9F CA C3 00 00 04 03 00 46 30 44 02 | ............F0D.
00000490: 20 67 13 FD 55 9E A9 9E 7E 49 AF 86 71 0B 42 CC |  g..U...~I..q.B.
000004A0: E9 E1 49 D0 EE 0C 97 CF BD A9 42 FB 89 A4 48 98 | ..I.......B...H.
000004B0: B4 02 20 26 0F 8C 47 4B AC DA 01 ED 7E 66 B6 AB | .. &..GK....~f..
000004C0: C7 63 B6 A8 00 C4 05 4D BB 91 F2 3B 4D 1B A1 4D | .c.....M...;M..M
000004D0: 85 D8 F6 00 76 00 46 A5 55 EB 75 FA 91 20 30 B5 | ....v.F.U.u.. 0.
000004E0: A2 89 69 F4 F3 7D 11 2C 41 74 BE FD 49 B8 85 AB | ..i..}.,At..I...
000004F0: F2 FC 70 FE 6D 47 00 00 01 7F 97 9F CC 94 00 00 | ..p.mG..........
00000500: 04 03 00 47 30 45 02 20 62 9A 39 CE A4 72 E6 1E | ...G0E. b.9..r..
00000510: 26 C4 0F CD 43 B5 68 1F FE 43 71 EE C7 EF CC D3 | &...C.h..Cq.....
00000520: 4D 23 CE 49 F9 37 4A 01 02 21 00 E6 BA 28 6B 5C | M#.I.7J..!...(k\
00000530: 4C 05 47 2D EE A0 EE 0F F4 31 64 DB 16 E4 61 8D | L.G-.....1d...a.
00000540: 5A 00 79 91 45 A4 67 74 39 E2 98 30 0D 06 09 2A | Z.y.E.gt9..0...*
00000550: 86 48 86 F7 0D 01 01 0B 05 00 03 82 01 01 00 29 | .H.............)
00000560: 5F 8C EC 91 F7 98 CC CD 65 E7 A4 52 DB 63 B4 62 | _.......e..R.c.b
00000570: 03 50 94 A2 BB F7 C9 C2 1C 9A F0 2D 4A 9C 35 C2 | .P.........-J.5.
00000580: 45 D2 DB 62 57 A3 40 E4 76 F7 DB 5C 58 B3 15 50 | E..bW.@.v..\X..P
00000590: 02 6E A2 16 D5 56 7B 8B                         | .n...V{.
id f442,total_len 26
dump mbuf at 0x1388649c0, iova=2781064a40, buf_len=2176
  pkt_len=40, ol_flags=c0000000000000, nb_segs=2, in_port=1
  segment at 0x1388649c0, data=0x138864ab2, data_len=34
  Dump data at [0x138864ab2], len=34
00000000: B4 A5 EF FE 4F 7B 7C E2 CA 28 46 4E 08 00 45 38 | ....O{|..(FN..E8
00000010: 00 1A F4 42 00 B9 FD 11 00 00 0A 1E 01 14 0A 1E | ...B............
00000020: 22 02                                           | ".
  segment at 0x12209e740, data=0x101b08a3a, data_len=6
  Dump data at [0x101b08a3a], len=6
00000000: F8 13 AF 59 84 02                               | ...Y..
[burst]id f442,total_len 1500
[burst]id f442,total_len 26
ret 2, len 2
[burst]id 0,total_len 96
ret 1, len 1
[burst]id f444,total_len 96
ret 1, len 1
[burst]id 0,total_len 88
ret 1, len 1
[burst]id 0,total_len 296
ret 1, len 1
[burst]id f447,total_len 88
ret 1, len 1
```

packet with nb_seg>1 cannot be capture after
call send_burst, but nb_seg==1 can be capture after send_burst.

Comment: Can you please update, NIC model number and firmware too.

Comment: waiting for the update on NIC model (SKU), firmware, sample application or code snippet that is used to produce multi-segment Ethernet frames. Can you please confirm that you looking for `multi-segment` and `not fragment or TSO` too.

Comment: NIC model: G73129-008
fw version:
driver: ixgbe
version: 5.1.0-k
firmware-version: 0x800007f5

Comment: I use rte_ipv4_frag_reassemble_packet to reassemble two packets to one packet(one mbuf with two segments),

Comment: as per your current update `ip fragment this big packet to two packets`. But this has nothing to do with multi-fragment. Do you want a call to clarify this?

Comment: small packet with one-segment can pass.
small packt with multi-segments cannot pass.

Comment: Share the code snippet you are using to reproduce the error

Comment: I updated the code content.

Comment: code shared is really confusing. Based on the `rte_pktmbuf_dump` it clearly shows there are 3 segments with 34, 48 and 1432 which adds up to 1514. Then in `send_burst` you are type casting mbuf to `struct rte_ipv4_hdr *` . before tx_burst the data in the logs are total size 1500 and ip payload as 26. This I believe is not correct, can recheck the code why IP total length is incorrect?

Comment: do_pkt_fragment divide into two packets
(1)id f442,total_len 1500 , add 14 bytes mac address pkt_len=1514
(2)
id f442,total_len 26, add 14 bytes mac address pkt_len=40

Comment: I have tried to use dpdk-pdump
But it always segmentation fault.
RING: Cannot reserve memory
EAL: Error - exiting with code: 1
  Cause: File exists
even I remove the dump file still the same.

Comment: As mentioned from the logs `ip payload as 26` and not `> 1400`, since you are using mbuf
 segment split and not fragment. Will you be able to d a live debug?

Comment: Joined now audio at your end

Comment: the solution to your issue is resolved in live debug. Please accept and upvote to close the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks @lsm for the live debug and call. We were able to narrow done to 3 major fixes

1. the default MTU for the PMD is `1514`, current reassembled to `1554` with 5 multi-segment.
2. the IPv4 payload length should be `1520` instead the code makes it `1500`.
3. Hardware offload flag `DEV_TX_OFFLOAD_MULTI_SEGS` is to updated to the new mbuf.

With these 3 fixes ***current update is the packet is transmitted properly***.